# Masking - Show div only on top of certain div?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, clip-path

I am trying to create an "eye blink" animation with HTML and CSS.

What I would want, is that when the eyes blink, the eyeballs are not showing.

As you can see from the code, the eyes consists of 4 elements.

Div "eyes" is the container where the eyes are.

Div "eye1" and "eye2".

Div "eyemask", that has the blinking effect.

Div "eyeball1" and "eyeball2". **These should only show on top of the "eyemask", not on top of the "eye1" and "eye2".**

Could someone help me to achieve this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#eyes {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#eye1,
#eye2 {
  z-index: 12;
}

#eye1,
#eye2,
#eyemask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}

#eye2 {
  transform: translateX(60px);
}

#eyemask {
  background: #fff;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

#eyeball1,
#eyeball2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Eyes.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="eyes">
      <div id="eye1">
        <div id="eyemask"></div>
        <div id="eyeball1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="eye2">
        <div id="eyemask"></div>
        <div id="eyeball2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Could someone here help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below and rely on a clip-path animation:

```css
.eyes {
  padding:20px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.eyes span{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background:grey;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
}
.eyes span:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:radial-gradient(black 7px, white 8px);
  animation:blink 0.8s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    clip-path: ellipse(50% 50% at 50% 50%);  
  }
  to {
    clip-path: ellipse(50%  0% at 50% 50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="eyes">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `#eyeball` inside the `#eyemask` and that should do it

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#eyes {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#eye1,
#eye2 {
  z-index: 12;
}

#eye1,
#eye2,
#eyemask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}

#eye2 {
  transform: translateX(60px);
}

#eyemask {
  background: #fff;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

#eyeball1,
#eyeball2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Eyes.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="eyes">
      <div id="eye1">
        <div id="eyemask">
          <div id="eyeball1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="eye2">
        <div id="eyemask">
          <div id="eyeball2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I would do if there wouldn't be any other solution. But what if, I would want only the white part to blink, not the eyeballs? With tools like Animate CC this is easy to achieve, but I was wondering if I can do this just with HTML and CSS.